# Xamarin upload image into folder and make folder share

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, google-drive-android-api

I want to upload an image to a specific folder and if that folder does not exist create it and make this folder shareable to another email address.
I use the below code:

```
                MetadataChangeSet changeSetfile = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()

                   .SetTitle("Test.jpg")
                   .SetMimeType("image/jpeg")
                   .Build();


            MetadataChangeSet changeSetfolder = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                                               .SetTitle("New folder")
                                               .SetMimeType(DriveFolder.MimeType)
                                               .SetStarred(true)
                                               .Build();

            DriveClass.DriveApi
             .GetRootFolder(_googleApiClient)
             .CreateFolder(_googleApiClient, changeSetfile) ;

            DriveClass.DriveApi
                     .GetRootFolder(_googleApiClient)
                      .CreateFile(_googleApiClient, changeSetfolder, contentResults.DriveContents);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to check if the folder exist. According to this tutorial - [Search files on Google Drive with C#](https://www.daimto.com/search-files-on-google-drive-with-c/), you can use:

> - **By file name**
>
>   - What if you know the name of the file or part of the name well you can search on name. Fulltext is also nice it allows you to search on “Full text of the file including name, description, content, and indexable text.”
> - **List files only directories**
>
>   - It is also possible to search for only one type of file say you just want to return all the Google sheets on your account? What if you just wanted to find all the folders well folders is a mimetype of “application/vnd.google-apps.folder” so we can search on just that.

Upon check if it is existing, get the ID to be place in the `parents` parameter:

```
var folderId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1TGRPeTVjaWRDY1E";
var fileMetadata = new File()
{
    Name = "photo.jpg",
    Parents = new List<string>
    {
        folderId
    }
};
FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("files/photo.jpg",
    System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    request = driveService.Files.Create(
        fileMetadata, stream, "image/jpeg");
    request.Fields = "id";
    request.Upload();
}
var file = request.ResponseBody;
Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);
```

Hope this helps.